# How to update Labels in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to create a program in where you put a word in a box, press add, and this word goes to a list, which is also displayed on the right side. When I press the forward button the first thing on the list is deleted. Problem is I can't get the labels to update when I press the buttons / edit the list.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Speakers List')
root.minsize(800, 600)

speakers = ['none']
spe = speakers[0]

def add():
    if spe == 'none':
        speakers.insert(0, [s])
        e.delete(0, END)
        spe.config(text=speakers[0])
    else:
        speakers[-2] = [s]
        e.delete(0, END)
        spe.config(text=speakers[0])
    return


def forward():
    if len(speakers) is 0:
        return
    else:
        del speakers[0]
        spe.config(text=speakers[0])
    return


entry = StringVar()
e = Entry(root, width=30, font=("Arial", 20), textvariable=entry)
e.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
s = e.get()

button1 = Button(root, padx=10, pady=10, bd=5, text='Add', fg='black', command=add)
button1.grid(row=0, column=1)

button2 = Button(root, padx=10, pady=10, bd=5, text='Next', fg='black', command=forward)
button2.grid(row=1, column=1)

n = Label(root, font=("Arial", 35), bd=2, text=spe)
n.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

listdisplay = Label(root, font=('Arial', 20), text=speakers)
listdisplay.grid(row=0, column=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When you click the buttons, you're not updating the `text` attribute of the labels. It seems you're trying to with `spe.config(text=speakers[0])`, but `spe` is a string, not a tkinter widget, right?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you were looking for ?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Speakers List')
root.minsize(800, 600)

speakers = ['50']
spe = speakers[0]

def add():
    entry=e.get()
    speakers.append(entry)
    listdisplay.config(text=speakers)
    return


def forward():
    if len(speakers) is 0:
        return
    else:
        del speakers[0]
    listdisplay.config(text=speakers)

    spe=speakers[0]
    n.config(text=spe)
    return


entry = StringVar()
e = Entry(root, width=30, font=("Arial", 20), textvariable=entry)
e.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
s = e.get()

button1 = Button(root, padx=10, pady=10, bd=5, text='Add', fg='black',command=add)
button1.grid(row=0, column=1)

button2 = Button(root, padx=10, pady=10, bd=5, text='Next', fg='black',command=forward)
button2.grid(row=1, column=1)

n = Label(root, font=("Arial", 35), bd=2, text=spe)
n.grid(row=1, sticky=W)

listdisplay = Label(root, font=('Arial', 20), text=speakers)
listdisplay.grid(row=0, column=10)


root.mainloop()
```

If so:
You create a list and then you use the append function to add an item to it. The rest was pretty much right.